# Blank screen while loading my Image on the android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-source, android-virtual-device

So I've compiled my own system.img along with userdata and the rest and I'm trying to test it on the android studio emulator.

I've tried copying above files to the avd folder, tried changing the sysdir path in the config.ini file, tried adding and installing a new package containing said files alongside the google_playstore folder but nothing seems to work.

Tried different builds to see if that was the issue but its the same. Hardware rendering also doesn't work.

In the event log, the Emulator: Process finishes with exit code 0 so I can't figure out why the screen is always blank.

Is it possible to test custom images on the studio emulator or should I test it on an actual device?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using system-qemu / vendor-qemu seems to have fixed it.